# Barcode4j generate barcode error

Tags: java, xslt, barcode, xalan, barcode4j

I'm using Barcode4j and FOP to generate a PDF that contains a barcode.
It works perfect on my Eclipse local environment, but after deploying to weblogic and accessing the function via web I get the following error:

> ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'org.krysalis.barcode4j.xalan.BarcodeExt.generate(result-tree, result-tree)' is not a valid object reference.'
>   FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

These are the sections of the stylesheet:

```
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:barcode="org.krysalis.barcode4j.xalan.BarcodeExt"
extension-element-prefixes="barcode"
exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
```

barcode generation:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
<xsl:variable name="barcodeNumber">
  <xsl:value-of select="barcodeNumber" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="barcode-cfg">
  <barcode>
    <intl2of5>
    <height>18mm</height>
    <module-width>0.28mm</module-width>
    <human-readable><placement>none</placement>
            </human-readable>
    </intl2of5>
  </barcode>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="barcode:generate($barcode-cfg, $barcodeNumber)" />
```

I'm using jdk 1.5.0_22, xalan-2.7.0, fop 1.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a namespace prefix for the barcode extension, you also have to use it. Otherwise, Xalan won't find the Java class necessary. So, write "barcode:barcode" and not just "barcode".